# Filter Results of a query with an object property using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to filter a `Results` variable on objects properties?

I have a list of products:

```
var products: Results<Product>!
```

Product is defined like this:

```
class Product: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var category: Category?
}
```

I can filter the products on the name property like this:

```
var filteredProducts = products.filter("name contains 'test'")
```

The question is: is it possible to filter the products having category in [category1, category2, category3] with a NSPredicate?

```
let arrCategories = [category1, category2, category3]
var filteredProducts = products.filter("category in %@", arrCategories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's supported by Realm.